# Removing duplicate results from a Map (Not techinally duplicate)

Tags: java, deserialization, xml-rpc, xmlrpcclient

I'm using www.opensubtitles.org API to get subtitles using file hash.
Now, my problem is that it returns all the available subtitles for that particular file.

for example:
I get this result when I select one file to download subtitles

https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2tZM.png

The whole result is here: http://privatepaste.com/download/22bb756930

The only difference between them is subtitle id and subtitle download links rest everything is same.

Now my problem is that this result is only for 1 file but I'll be using multiple files so it's not possible to get the first most result and use it.

The code to retrieve the result is given below

```
    Map<?, ?> result = (Map<?, ?>) rpcClient.execute("SearchSubtitles", params);
    Object[] data = (Object[]) result.get("data");
    Map<?, ?>[] results = new Map<?, ?>[data.length];
    int i = 0;
    for (Object element : data) {
        results[i] = (Map<?, ?>) element; //storing it in map
        i++;
    }
```

Now what I want is that when I choose let's say 12 files I want only 1 result to be stored for each of them and not 3 in the above case.

I did got it working but my code clearly is not good.
I wrote this at 3 in the morning and took me 5 minutes because my only goal was to get it working.

```
    Map<?, ?> result = (Map<?, ?>) rpcClient.execute("SearchSubtitles", params);
    Object[] data = (Object[]) result.get("data");
    Map<?, ?>[] results = new Map<?, ?>[data.length];
    int i = 0;
    for (Object element : data) {
        System.out.println(element);
        results[i] = (Map<?, ?>) element;
        i++;
    }
    List<String> idmbIDs = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Map<?, ?> map : results) {
        String string = (String) map.get("IDMovieImdb");
        if (!idmbIDs.contains(string))
            idmbIDs.add(string); //stores distinct idmb ids.
    }
    List<String> removedIDMBids = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String store : idmbIDs) {
        for (Map<?, ?> map : results) {
            if (store.contains((String) map.get("IDMovieImdb")) && !removedIDMBids.contains(store)) {
                removedIDMBids.add(store);
                fileDetails.add(map);
            }
        }
    }
    for (Map<?, ?> realResult : fileDetails) {
        System.out.println(realResult); <- this does what I want
    }
```

I want a better way to do something like this.
It would be great if I can get the most downloaded subtitles using the `(map.get("SubDownloadsCnt");`

Any help would be appreciated.
Pardon me if I'm not able to explain it properly.
and please don't neg.

Comment: Ok, well before asking us to fix your code up.... have you tried doing it yourself? What is your cleaned-up code after having spent more than fie minutes on it (at a time when you're well-rested)?

Comment: Secondly: Stack Overflow works best with specific technical problems. This is a very general question about refactoring your code... it doesn't fit as well. Can you perhaps reformulate your question to be a specific, technical question that has an answer, rather than "help me make my code better" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather create a `Subtitle` class with `equals` overriden (`@Override`) (re implemented), and there I will discriminate where to objects are equals or not.

Your `Subtitle` class will have all the properties that you get in the response, as `SeriesIMDBParent`, `IDSubtitle`, etc.

On that object you can create a constructor (or method `load`) that receives a `Map<?, ?>[]` parameter which you will use to load the values to to object. Or you can be smarter and user the [Dozer Mapping](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/mapbackedproperty.html), that will help you to do this job automatically.

And then your code will look something like:

```
    BeanMappingBuilder builder = new BeanMappingBuilder() {
        protected void configure() {
            mapping(Map.class, Subtitle.class, mapNull(false))
            .
            .
            .
        }
     }
```

After configuring the mapping you will have to make it possible with:

```
Map<String, Object> result = (Map<String, Object>) rpcClient.execute("SearchSubtitles", params);
Subtitle subtitle = new Subtitle();
mapper.map(result, subtitle)
```

;

After this and having implemented the `equals` and `hashCode` methods, you will be able to use a `Set<Subtitle>` (for example) which will force the `Set` to have unique objects based on the criteria you implemented to differentiate between objects.

Comment: "On that object you can create a constructor (or method load) that receives a Map<?, ?>[] parameter which you will use to load the values to to object."
Could you please explain this again?
And no, I will not be using the Dozer thing because I don't know what it is and I really don't have time to learn it. (This is project which I have to submit).
Thank you so very much for answering.

Comment: Yes.
I didn't knew about equals and hashcode
Lol.
Thanks!